# Reciving several Arduino sensors value through serial data into a C#/WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port, arduino

I'm using C# UI to control the Arduino board, and it works perfectly. I'm sending commands and values using a text protocol. But, I can't figure out how to receive multiple sensor values from Arduino to C#.

From C# to Arduino, I'm using a ASCII chart in the beginning and end of the string to determine where the values should be stored in Arduino. In Arduino:

```
void serial_Sensitivity_command(){
    if (Serial.available()){
        while (Serial.available() >= 0){
            if (inChar == SOFF){
                dex1 = 0;
                inData_sens[dex1] = '\0';
                started1 = true;
                ended1 = false;
            }
            else
                if (inChar == EOFF){
                    ended1 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (dex1 < 9){
                        inData_sens[dex1] = inChar;
                        dex1++;
                        inData_sens[dex1] = '\0';
                    }
                }

                if (started1 && ended1){
                    sensitivity_gain = atoi(inData_sens);
                    started1 = false;
                    ended1 = false;
                    dex1 = 0;
                    inData_sens[dex1] = '\0';
                }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to route eight different values to each textblock in C#. Is there a similar way to use in C# like I did in Arduino?

Or should I read string array and then use Substring?

Comment: Just add an extra byte after SOFF that indicates the value number.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the string protocol, but I have successfully used the serial port over [USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus).

In Arduino:

```
//Reading in
while(Serial.available(){
    unsigned char c;
    c = Serial.read();
    if (c == EOFF)
        <process input>
    else
        <buffer input>
}

//sending out
Serial.write(byte1);
Serial.write(byte2);
....
Serial.write(<End of stream marker);
```

Then in C#, you can use `System.IO.Ports` using the SerialPort to read the data and collect the data in the same format.